# Resigning in Two Months due to Family Health Issues.

Tags: resignation, health, family

I had a delayed start with this company due to a family member's health.

This is a role which is very hard to fill (it was open for more than a year in a 100 person company). I got an offer a few months back. Unfortunately, a family member became quite sick, and **I had to stop the process a week of days after I had accepted the offer letter**.  Felt very bad doing that, but they were quite understanding.

After a few months, **the family member's health became more stable**. At around this time, the recruiter reached out to me again, asking if I was still interested in this role. They were not able to find anyone for this role since that time.

**I accepted to join on the same terms as before as the health issue seemed resolved.** Now fast forward two more months. The family member's health issue has cropped up again. It is obvious now, I am pretty sure I cannot balance the health of this person and a full time job.

I would need to take a break for 6 months to a year (and possibly more) for this health issue. This means me quitting the job (just two months after joining).

I feel bad as the company is quite nice. The people are professional and friendly. On other hand, this personal issue will require more and more of my time. I am looking at a less demanding (and less financially beneficial) position that will be more optimal. (I have an open offer to join an old company for a much lesser salary but ultimately with more personal time which is what I need).

**Am I the devil for quitting again?** How will this be taken?

Comment: Am I the devil for quitting again? How will this be taken?, you'll find out when you quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely not the devil.

Everyone invests time, effort and money into relationships. Whatever your investment may be, you will find that you'll have to let go at a certain point in time.

Your situation is the same. Your new company may have invested in you, but it'll have to let you go since life demands your presence elsewhere(with family).

Remember it is only family that stays by you in times of need. The company can only offer support for a limited period before they move on.

Answer (score 2):

If they can't fill that job so easily you may ask them to change your contract as a part-time job ? It's better for them than an empty chair and should let you being able to take care of your family.